# Create virtual host for Laravel using Xampp with the port 8003

Tags: windows, laravel, laravel-5, xampp, localhost

I am trying to create a virtual host for my project using Xampp.

- I added `127.0.0.1       project.com` in the `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
- I changed the port `80` to `8003` in the `httpd.conf` file in `C:\xampp\apache\conf` (I changed everything from `80` to `8003` in this file)
- I added this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
    ServerName project.com
</VirtualHost>
```

in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

When I leave it with the 80 port in the files, it works good. But when I try to use the 8003 port does not work. I get the same message as when I stop Apache.

**Edit1:** I changed this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8003>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
    ServerName project.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can access to the ulr but just if I try with the url like this: `project.com::8003`
With the number port at the end of the url. 
There is a way to use project.com without add the number port?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check 4 things.

1. Are you sure you are listening to port 8003 in **httpd.conf** file.
2. Set `ServerName domainName.com:8003` in **httpd-vhosts.conf**.
3. You also need to change: VirtualHost *:8003 in **httpd-vhosts.conf**.

`<VirtualHost *:8003>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
    ServerName project.com
</VirtualHost>`

4. Now, you should be able to access with your URL: **http://domainName.com:8003**

last but not the least don't forget to restart xampp.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I just can access to the url if I put the number port at the end?

Comment: You mean.. can't access right?. Have you checked all the above 4 things I have mentioned

Comment: Yes, I can access to http://project.com:8003 but I want to know If I have to use obligatorily the port number at the end of the URL, in this case 8003

Comment: Okay.. The HTTP protocol uses port 80 by default. If you configure your web server to use a nonstandard port, then the port needs to be specified in the URL.